# Read Low Level Mouse Click Unix passed through PuTTY

Tags: c++, unix, putty, xterm, tui

I use PuTTY to connect to a shell (Unix Server). I can use the mouse to select Text from the CLI. Also, vim can also interact with the mouse, so I know that PuTTY does send mouse input to the server.

My problem is that I want to capture the mouse events in a C++ TUI , much like vim does (just, I will be handling them differently). I have gone through many sites, but none of them describes my problem precisely. I have a feeling that I will need xterm, but I don't know how to use it!

The best links that I found are :

[How to read low level mouse click position in linux .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519759/how-to-read-low-level-mouse-click-position-in-linux)

[Weird insertion from Vim on mouse click](https://superuser.com/questions/413351/weird-insertion-from-vim-on-mouse-click#comment471871_413351) --> How do I read this event?

[A blessed UI for Jitsu](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/a-blessed-ui-for-jitsu) --> Hats off to this guy!

Can anyone provide a sample code to read the mouse location? I can code the rest of the application then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work just fine to do this using the mouse-interface in `ncurses` (I'm sure that vim and other applications has no specific knowledge about how SSH/PuTTY communicates, it just picks up the mouse position as it would if it was a local connection - the `sshd` sorts out all the magic with translating network packets to keypresses and mouse-moves).

[Here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/mouse.html) is a description of how you interface with a mouse in `ncurses`.