# Linux X11 C Want to know pointer motion anywhere on screen

Tags: c, linux, hook, x11

I want to write a small window program that will display the pointer position (and other info) anywhere on the screen. I do not want to disrupt the normal use of the mouse in all the other programs running. Is there a way to "hook" pointer motion events, or how can I set up a timer event for polling the pointer position in my event loop?

Comment: Check the code of the xev tool (is in the x11-utils package on Debian based systems).

Comment: @Fernando I don't see anything in xev that is applicable. But I think I have found a solution. I will code it tomorrow and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point you at the [Xautolock code queryPointer function](http://fossies.org/dox/xautolock-2.2/engine_8c_source.html#l00058), which figures out the mouse position. If you dig around in `main.c` and `diy.c`, you should also get enough information about what is necessary to take action based on mouse mouse cursor position and idle timeouts.

Effectively, it just uses [XQueryPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html) to get the information. However, you should keep in mind that all mouse movements are relative, so you must keep state based on the initial position. Example code for this is found in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519759/how-to-read-low-level-mouse-click-position-in-linux).

### Edit

Since it's not apparently obvious from the Xautolock code, I cribbed the bits that do what I think you're looking for. This is a minimal set of code that just dumps the x / y coordinates to stdout. If you want them statically, you'll have to create and position a window to draw some text to. Polling with a resolution of 1ms as this code does, the program takes roughly 0.1% CPU on my machine (`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4558U CPU @ 2.80GHz`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>

static Window root;

static void
query_pointer(Display *d)
{
  static int once;
  int i, x, y;
  unsigned m;
  Window w;

  if (once == 0) {
    once = 1;
    root = DefaultRootWindow(d);
  }

  if (!XQueryPointer(d, root, &root, &w, &x, &y, &i, &i, &m)) {
    for (i = -1; ++i < ScreenCount(d); ) {
      if (root == RootWindow(d, i)) {
        break;
      } 
    }
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "X: %d Y: %d\n", x, y);
}

static int
catchFalseAlarm(void)
{
  return 0;
}   

int 
main(void)
{
  XSetWindowAttributes attribs;
  Display* d;
  Window w;

  if (!(d = XOpenDisplay(0))) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't connect to %s\n", XDisplayName (0));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  attribs.override_redirect = True;
  w = XCreateWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow (d), -1, -1, 1, 1, 0,
         CopyFromParent, InputOnly, CopyFromParent,
         CWOverrideRedirect, &attribs);
  XMapWindow(d, w);
  XSetErrorHandler((XErrorHandler )catchFalseAlarm);
  XSync (d, 0);

  for (;;) {
    query_pointer(d);
    usleep(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I tried the code I get `opening device: Permission denied`. I don't want to have to be root.

Comment: Check out how xautolock uses XQueryPointer, it definitely doesn't need root permissions. I was more referring to the SO thread as a self-contained example of using XQueryPointer.

Comment: XQueryPointer looks workable, but the 'hook' needing to get a list of all the windows etc. looks way worse than I thought. How about the timer and polling idea instead?

Comment: I've added some code that implements a poller. It's 100% cribbed from xautolock.

Comment: I want to do other things also in my event loop, so I don't want to use sleep. I've got the XQueryPointer part done, so it's down to perhaps getting a timer set to send me an event every 200 miliseconds (or whatever) without holding up other events. Thanks for your help.

Comment: this code does not compile cleanly, the compiler raises 5 warnings: 1) implicit declaration of function usleep() 2) unused parameter argv 3) unused parameter argc 4) unused parameter event for catchfalseAlarm() 5) unused parameter d in catchFalseAlarm()

Comment: Compiles fine with clang -Wall, not with -Wextra. I'll update the code to compile cleanly here, as well. Thanks for the mention. Update: still fails with -Weverything in clang, because the return from main is unreachable; I don't much care to fix that.