# Why the mouse move events aren't generated globally in Xlib?

Tags: c, xlib

I want `XEvent` to receive mouse move events, `MotionNotify`, wherever the cursor is even if it is not in the window, so I decided to listen to the root window events. The code snippet I have tried is as following:

```
Event e;
Display d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Window w = RootWindow(d, 0), win = XCreateWindow(...);
XSelectInput(d, w, PointerMotionMask);

......

while(true)
{
    XNextEvent(d, &e);
    ......
}
```

Why the mouse move events aren't generated if the cursor is out of `win` window?

Comment: Learn about grabbing the mouse in X11

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux X11 C Want to know pointer motion anywhere on screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722770/linux-x11-c-want-to-know-pointer-motion-anywhere-on-screen)